# How to add target="_blank" to JavaScript window.location?

Tags: javascript

The following sets the target to `_blank`:

```
if (key == "smk") {
    window.location = "http://www.smkproduction.eu5.org";
    target = "_blank";
    done = 1;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How do I launch the link in a new tab?

Here is my code:

```js
function ToKey() {
  var done = 0;
  var key = document.tokey.key.value;
  key = key.toLowerCase();
  if (key == "smk") {
    window.location = "http://www.smkproduction.eu5.org";
    target = "_blank"
    done = 1;
  }
  if (done == 0) {
    alert("Kodi nuk është valid!");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="tokey">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Type the key</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="key">
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Go" onClick="ToKey()">
      </td>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: So you want to open a url in a new window?

Comment: Yepp?! only if the key is right...

Comment: where the `HEAD` closes?

Answer (score 386, accepted):

`window.location` sets the URL of your current window. To open a new window, you need to use `window.open`. This should work:

```
function ToKey(){
    var key = document.tokey.key.value.toLowerCase();
    if (key == "smk") {
        window.open('http://www.smkproduction.eu5.org', '_blank');
    } else {
        alert("Kodi nuk është valid!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @twinlakes this gets blocked in all modern browsers.

Comment: @BenRacicot well yes, popups are blocked by default and most people don't change that

Comment: the problem with window.open is the pop-blocked blocker

Answer (score 87):

Just use in your `if (key=="smk")`

```
if (key=="smk") { window.open('http://www.smkproduction.eu5.org','_blank'); }
```

Answer (score 20):

if you want to open a link in new tab `window.open` has a problem,
my firefox detect a popup link by using `window.open`' and this is not good

I was handle this by using the latest comment

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = 'https://example.com';
anchor.target="_blank";
anchor.click();
```

Comment: This is the best way to prevent popup

Comment: I can confirm that it works perfectly on chrome 99. Thanks!

Comment: i try this but still "pop-up blocked" in google chrome

Answer (score 17):

I have created a function that allows me to obtain this feature:

```
function redirect_blank(url) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.target="_blank";
  a.href=url;
  a.click();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. probably a recent browsers policy update?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<a href="http://www.smkproduction.eu5.org" onclick="window.open('http://www.smkproduction.eu5.org', '_blank');return false;"></a>
```

before that you can replace the event in onclick, window.open will not be blocked by the browser if called explicitly

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, and it was so simple using javascript

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = 'https://example.com';
anchor.target="_blank";
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything do with the question, which is about triggering navigation directly and not using a link to do it.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    var linkGo = function(item) {
      $(item).on('click', function() {
        var _$this = $(this);
        var _urlBlank = _$this.attr("data-link");
        var _urlTemp = _$this.attr("data-url");
        if (_urlBlank === "_blank") {
          window.open(_urlTemp, '_blank');
        } else {
          // cross-origin
          location.href = _urlTemp;
        }
      });
    };

    linkGo(".button__main[data-link]");
```

```css
.button{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="button button__main" data-link="" data-url="https://stackoverflow.com/">go stackoverflow</span>
```