# Using jQuery, is it possible to open a file in a new tab on all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

I need to modify a form submission script to open a PDF in a new tab upon success.

As it stands, when it succeeds, it already shows a notice of thanks and clears the form. I just need the jQuery to open the PDF in a new tab. I've only been able to open a new window with `window.open()`, which is promptly blocked as a pop-up.

Comment: by default `window.open()` should open a new tab if no window name is specified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add target="\_blank" to JavaScript window.location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476373/how-to-add-target-blank-to-javascript-window-location)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Would the fact that it's not being used with a click event make a difference?

Comment: Well, you *want* a popup?

Comment: You should find an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628949/window-open-popup-getting-blocked-during-click-event).

Comment: New windows only open in new tabs **if I've allowed it** in my browser settings.  (You cannot over-ride the browser's handling of this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly control this; it's down to the browser and its settings.

jQuery is JavaScript, so there's nothing jQuery can possibly provide that isn't available to you in native JS, and all JS provides is `window.open()`, which, as you've found out, is normally blocked unless it's the result of a (real, not simulated) click event.