# Open specific JS in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in JS:

```
function Loremos() {
    var username = document['Wybor']['lang'].value;
    if (username.length != 0) {
        window.location = "http://twitter." + language;
    }
}
```

In HTML

```
<a href="javascript:Loremos();" target="_blank">twitter</a>
```

I want to open this in new tab and it doesn't work. What I done wrong?

Comment: does it open and you can't get it to open in a new tab or does it just not open at all? if it does nothing are there errors in your browsers developer tools console?

Comment: `language` isn't defined in your code

Comment: @b3ko its not opening in new card/window but in the same

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I tried those ideas and these doesn't work for me.

Comment: check out this answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476373/how-to-add-target-blank-to-javascript-window-location