# Proper javascript redirect that works with "Open link in new tab"

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, anchor, tr

Is there a way to create a link using JavaScript that acts exactly like an `<a>` tag? In other words, when you click it normally, it opens in the current window and when you right click, it shows "Open link in a new tab" under options. And if you click it, it does open in a new tab.

I am not interested in solutions that add an `<a>` tag into the html, because the main reason I am asking this is that I need to apply this link to a `<tr>` element.

***Edit:** Please consider that this needs to work with keyboard shorcuts (such as cmd+click on a mac) as well as right click and "Open in new tab"*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476373/how-to-add-target-blank-to-javascript-window-location

Comment: If you need standard context menu I pretty sure that this is impossible. If you want to implement custom context menu it's possible to open url via `window.open('http://...', '_blank')` and for usual click check if Cmd was pressed.

Comment: True, but you can use the `keyCode` in your JavaScript function to either open in `_blank` or just do `document.location.href`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's no way to have Javascript function exactly like an HTML a tag. Still, you can emulate it. There might be better solutions out there, but what I'd research is how to emulate each of those actions of clicking on a link.

You'll want to handle...

1. Cursor change (hover, active, current, etc.)
2. Determine if you want to re-direct or run javascript/JQuery.

If you opt for a redirect, you don't have to handle as much else (just #4 below). The browser will do the redirect and it will be like clicking on an HTML a tag.

If you want to run code, then you'll have to handle more. This includes...

3. Adding history to the browser, to help when the user initiates the back command. In and HTML5-enabled this is relatively easy. In HTML4, you'll want to use JQuery or something else.
4. Adding mechanics for right-click, etc. You'll have to emulate that. This part is a royal pain, because now you're trying to interfere/replace with the browser operations.

So if you're up for that, more power to you. However I'd strongly recommend adding an  tag into the  of your  and then setting the a link to go nowhere (either "" or "#") and adding "onclick" to that tag to run javascript. Fortunately onclick works with the keyboard too for  tags, not just a mouse click (http://websiteaccessibility.donaldevans.com/2011/06/30/when-does-onclick-work-with-the-keyboard-enter-key/)

Answer (score 12):

Use `window.open(url, '_blank')` to open it a new target window