# Make link open in new window , javascript on html table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with linking in my table.

I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
        });
    });
</script>
```

And it works without flaws, but I can't make links open in new window using standard html code:

```
target="_blank"
```

in:

```
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="http://www.google.com/">
```

doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: how hard is it to search google for `open new window javascript`  or similar terms? Questions asked here should show at least some research effort was attempted

Comment: you code should be `window.open($(this).data("href"));`

Comment: Of course I know that. I need just some links to be opened in new window, not all of them. I do not post Q that are easy to solve with google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        if(this.hasAttribute("target")){
            window.open($(this).data("href"),$(this).data("target"));
        }
        else{
            window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
        }
    });
});
```

That checks if the `<a>` has a target attribute, and uses it if it does.

### [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdQWxv)

**EDIT:**
Here is the solution to your comment:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        if(this.getAttribute("href").substr(this.getAttribute("href").length - 3)=== "###"){
            window.open(this.getAttribute("href").substring(0, this.getAttribute("href").length-3),"_blank");
        }
        else{
            window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hmm, it works, but, I have another problem. Visual Composer "eats" target . Can you please rewrite this so that if the a href link contains ### in address, it opens in new tab? Example: www.google.com/### = new tab and www.google.com = same tab.

Comment: Or I can assign additional class.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thx!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help :D

Answer (score 1):

`window.open('href')`

Window location sets your current window's location.

Comment: But that will open all the links in the new window. I just need it to accept target="_blank". I need to open just some links in new window. Not all of them.

Comment: @JackBauer I would use Jacob's answer then

Answer (score 0):

What about using `window.open="http://....","target="_blank")`

[SO Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476373/how-to-add-target-blank-to-javascript-window-location)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding two classes and two functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".istiprozor").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
$(".noviprozor").click(function() {
       window.open($(this).data("href"),$(this).data("target"));
    });
});
    </script>
```