# How to give target_blank for an input type submit and onclick javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scripting function in my html code.I have a input type "submit" which is like this.

```
<input type="submit" value="View PO" onclick="generate()"/>
```

When i click on submit it is going to the "generate()" function and it is opening the page in the same tab. But i need to open the page in a new tab.
I know that "target_blank" will resolve this.But when i am putting "target_blank" in input type it is not properly responding.So any help will be appreciated

Comment: target="_blank" is not an attribute of input type text. You can use <a href="" target="_blank"> or you can use javascript redirect under your function: 
  var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
  window.open(url, '_blank');

Comment: you can set window.open('url') on your function. please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476373/how-to-add-target-blank-to-javascript-window-location

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open`

```
var generate = function(){

    // your stuff here...

    var url = "you url here";
    window.open(url);
}
```