# Build a URL that opens in a new window from form fields

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I am building a custom url based on form field inputs and javascript. Everything is working the way it is, but I would like the url that gets built to open in a new window. Is that possible?

It's a little booking widget, a calendar will pop out on click of the date boxes and that part works too. I really would just like it to open in a new window on submit.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(function() {
 var form = jQuery('form#form1');
 form.submit(function(e) {
  var checkin = form.find('input[name="from"]').val();
  var nights = form.find('input[name="nights"]').val();
  var guests = form.find('input[name="number"]').val();
        
  window.location = "https://example.com" + checkin + ";" + nights + ";" + guests + ";?"; 
   return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="book-popup">
          <a class="opener btn" href="#">Book Now</a>
          <div class="slide">

<form id="form1" method="POST" target="_blank" class="timer-box" >

         
 
              <div class="selections">

                <div class="set">

                  <strong class="title">Arrival</strong>

                  <div class="frame">

                    <em class="month"><?php echo date("M") ?></em>

                    <span class="date-text"><?php echo date("j") ?></span>

                    <input type="hidden" name="from" class="from" value="<?php echo date("mdY") ?>">

                    <a href="#" class="btn-down icon-chevron-thin-down"></a>

                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="set">

                  <strong class="title">Nights</strong>

                 <div class="frame">

                    <input type="number" name="nights" value="1" max="8" min="1">

                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="set">

                  <strong class="title">Guests</strong>

                  <div class="frame">

                    <input type="number" name="number" value="2" max="8" min="1">

                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>

            <div class="col">  <input type="submit" value="BOOK NOW" class="btn" >
      
            
              </div>

            </form>
            
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: See the answer at this link... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476373/how-to-add-target-blank-to-javascript-window-location?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `window.open` instead of `window.location`:

```
window.open('http://your-url.com','_blank');
```

Answer (score 2):

window.location will update the url of the current page. Try window.open().
You should be able to just pass in the url.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following

```
 window.open(‘url’)
```