# Including target _blank in jquery location.href

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to make a jquery function that has `location.href` open a new TAB and not a new window. I do not want to have pop up blockers come into play. I am simply trying to open a tab and not direct users away from the site.

This is what I currently have.

```
<a onclick="url();" target="_blank">Click this</a>

function url() {

 location.href = 'users.php?id=' + ID;

}
```

However, this is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add target="\_blank" to JavaScript window.location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476373/how-to-add-target-blank-to-javascript-window-location)

Answer (score 1):

just use window.open instead of location.href

```
window.open('www.google.com', '_blank');
```

Comment: Window open, opens new windows, not tabs. And window open is blocked by most pop up blockers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mention your question in jQuery tag, I solved your problem in jQuery way. Hope this will help you.

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(){
  $(this).attr('href','users.php?id=1')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='link' target="_blank">Click this</a>
```