# target _blank not working with download attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a success page in a new tab after clicking on the download link, but target _blank not working with download attribute. Please Help Me......

Button HTML

```
<a class="btn download-btn" id="myButton" href="https://www.uiuxstream.com/download/404-error-page-not-found-design-html.html" target="_blank" download>Download</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "/demo/thank-you-for-downloading.php";

};
```

Comment: I think the `target` attribute only affects the `a`. Trying changing `location.href`. (Also there is no PHP relation here, no jquery. Please only tag relevant languages)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add target="\_blank" to JavaScript window.location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476373/how-to-add-target-blank-to-javascript-window-location)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any purpose your `download` attribute is serving in your code

Comment: There's no need for the _target attribute.

Answer (score -1):

in the `<a>`, remove the `href`, add `onclick="go()", and in a script, add:

```
function go() {
  open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
  location.href = "http://mail.google.com";
}
```

Good luck!
if you are familiar with event listeners, you could use that instead to call `go()`.

Comment: So, is this a good answer?  If so, please select and up-vote it - thanks!